# How to get data from nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel-9

I have 3 database tables (users, marketplaces, orders). One user can have many marketplaces and one marketplace has a morphMany relationship with orders.
My user model:
`

```
public function marketplaces(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Marketplace::class);
}
```

`Marketplace model:`

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'orderable');
}
```

`

I need to retrive the orders which is ordered by a spacific user through his many marketplaces.
How can I do that with the help or eloquent in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve nested relationships with Eloquent, you have to use `with` function. For example:

```
$user = User::with('marketplaces')->first();
```

or

```
$user = User::with('marketplaces.orders')->first();
```

The second example brings every order that is related on each marketplace that is connected with the user.
You can also use function to build your own query inside the `with` if you want to add some conditions on the query. For example:

```
$user = User::with(['marketplaces.orders' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 1);
}]);
```